# PCI-e SATA III controller with 4 ports

Tags: ssd, sata, raid-controller

On my motherboard no SATA3 controller. I want to purchase a separate high-quality controller that can simultaneously process 4 SSD drives at maximum speed and performance.

Required the controller to operate simultaneously at a speed of 6 Gbps on each port.

(RAID function is not needed)

Comment: Something [like this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816124064) looks like it fills all your requirements, it has good reviews for the most part as well.

Comment: NOT! This card PCI-Express 2.0 1x This means that the maximum transfer rate 5 GT/s (500 MB/s). 4 SSD drive SATA III need  4 x 6 GT/s (4 x 750 MB/s) as a result need 24 GT/s  (3000 MB/s). Сard should be PCI-Express 2.0 8x

Comment: Theoretically, probably be some  like RAID controller PCI-Express 2.0 8x with JBOD mode

Comment: May I ask why you need to drive 4 SSDs off a single controller without hardware RAID?

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be very difficult to find a quad port SATA controller that *does not* have RAID capabilities built in so you might as well get it with RAID and just not turn on that feature.  It is nice, however, to know that you can go RAID if you want to later down the line.

That said, I would stay away from the smaller brands that don't have a strong reputation.  I have used RAID from [LSI Logic (now Avago)](http://www.avagotech.com/products/storage/) because they are the OEM manufacturer for some big names like Dell and Apple.    In fact, you can get Dell and Apple branded RAID controllers to work in pretty much any machine; I have done so in the past.

For your application, you just need a simple quad port SATA RAID controller like the [LSI Logic 9211-4i](https://goo.gl/6hd9TF).  Just remember, you will need the mini SAS to SATA breakout cable.

Answer (score -1):

You're gonna need server-grade PCI-E bandwidth.
[IBM-ServeRaid-M5110-8-Port-6Gbps-PCI-e-SAS-SATA-RAID-Controller-81Y4481-81Y4482](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007V8S0HY)

you'll need to make sure you get some SAS to SATA breakout cables, but these drives offer serious I/O for a decent price. Consumer grade RAID cards usually fail to satisfy your needs because of insufficient PCI-E bandwidth, while modern equivalents will not really be affordable. In my experience the only difficulty is in making sure you get the drivers (but since they are well-supported this is not really an issue after all).

Small note: if you don't have at least one PCI-E 8x 2.0 connection, you're boned. You may also be boned if you have lots of other devices occupying PCI-E slots.